# CodeMirror simple mode - regex not highlighting as expected

Tags: javascript, regex, codemirror

I'm trying to use [CodeMirror simple mode](http://codemirror.net/demo/simplemode.html) to create my own editor and highlight some custom keywords. However, it's highlighting occurrences of these words inside other words. Here's my code to define the mode of the editor:

```
    CodeMirror.defineSimpleMode("simple", {
  // The start state contains the rules that are intially used
  start: [
    // The regex matches the token, the token property contains the type
    {regex: /["'](?:[^\\]|\\.)*?(?:["']|$)/, token: "string"},
    {regex: /;.*/, token: "comment"},
    {regex: /\/\*/, token: "comment", next: "comment"},

    {regex: /[-+\/*=<>!]+/, token: "operator"},
    {regex: /[\{\[\(]/, indent: true},
    {regex: /[\}\]\)]/, dedent: true},

    //Trying to define keywords here
    {regex: /\b(?:timer|counter|version)\b/gi, token: "keyword"} // gi for case insensitive
  ],
  // The multi-line comment state.
  comment: [
    {regex: /.*?\*\//, token: "comment", next: "start"},
    {regex: /.*/, token: "comment"}
  ],
  meta: {
    dontIndentStates: ["comment"],
    lineComment: ";"
  }
});
```

When I type in the editor, this is what gets highlighted. I would expect the first two occurrences to be styled, but not the second two.

[image]

It's obviously something incorrect with this regular expression:

```
/\b(?:timer|counter|version)\b/gi
```

But I've tried it several different ways and the same pattern works correctly in other regex testers. Example:
https://regex101.com/r/lQ0lL8/33 . Any advice?

#### Edit #1:

Tried this pattern in codemirror definition, dropping the /g but it still yields the same incorrect highlighting.

```
{regex: /\b(?:timer|counter|version)\b/i, token: "keyword"}
```

Comment: You should drop the `/g` modifier: `/\b(?:timer|counter|version)\b/i`.   I don't know if it's the cause of your problem, but it definitely isn't needed.  Otherwise, the regex looks fine.

Comment: @AlanMoore Thanks, I did try that but still got the same result. Removing the `/g`modifier [limited my matches here though](https://regex101.com/r/asqpQA/1).

Comment: What does it do with the word `timerNO`?  That is, does the `\b` at the end work?

Comment: @AlanMoore this pattern `{regex: /\b(?:timer|counter|version)\b/i, token: "keyword"}` does not highlight `timerNO`. Does it seem like it's not respecting the `/b` at the beginning?

Comment: I suspect it's treating the beginning of the match as the beginning of the string.  If that's the case, then a regex like `/\b!bar/` won't match anywhere, even in `foo!bar`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up just defining my own mode from scratch and the additional customization seems to have worked. I parse the stream by word, convert to lowercase, then check if it's in my list of keywords. Using this approach it seems very straightforward to add additional styles and keywords.

```
var keywords = ["timer", "counter", "version"];

CodeMirror.defineMode("mymode", function() {

  return {
    token: function(stream, state) {
      stream.eatWhile(/\w/);

      if (arrayContains(stream.current(), keywords)) {
        return "style1";
      }
      stream.next();
    }
  };

});


var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('cm'), {
  mode: "mymode",
  lineNumbers: true
});

function arrayContains(needle, arrhaystack) {
  var lower = needle.toLowerCase();
  return (arrhaystack.indexOf(lower) > -1);
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/colinwurtz/TcqAf/427/)