# Regex: "AND OR" returns two groups, "ANDOR" returns no groups

Tags: regex

I am looking for regex which returns:

input: `AND OR NOT`

expected output:
`group 0:"AND"`
`group 1:"OR"`
`group 2:"NOT"`

input: `ANDOR NOT`

expected output:
`group 0:"NOT"`

In short, my regex should return groups containing logical expression only if they are separated by `space`.

Spent 3 hours, asked 4 colleagues and I still do not know how to do it.

My approaches:

`{ regex: /( AND )|( OR )|( NOT )/, token: "logical" }`

it does not work because for `AND NOT` I do not get expected result.

`{ regex: /(AND)|(OR)|(NOT)/, token: "logical" },`

it does not work because for `ANDNOT` I do not get expected result.

`{ regex: /(?:(AND)|(OR)|(NOT))/, token: "logical" },`

it does not work because for `ANDOR` I do not get expected result.

Please help :-)

Comment: Why do you need them in different groups? why not just matches as shown [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/5MdEoY/1) - `\b(?:AND|OR|NOT)\b`

Comment: Because `ANDOR` will be returned as true and it should not.

Comment: @JacekWojcik If you were to follow his example that he illustrated in his link, no it would not. That's why he chose a word bound outside of the `match everything enclosed` grouping.

Comment: Knowing what engine you use is important. BTW if the workaround  with word boundaries doesn't behave as expected in all situations you may use `(?<!\S)(?:AND|OR|NOT)(?!\S)` (assuming the engine supports lookbehinds)

Comment: I made my own mode for `CodeMirror`. 

Answer by Gurman does not work. 

Answer by revo does not work work either. 

I made another answer which kind of makes sense on regex101: 

`{ regex: /((?<= )OR(?= ))|((?<= )AND(?= ))|(^AND(?= ))/g, token: "logical"}` 

but it does not work either

Comment: Looks like this is a problem with `CodeMirror`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40745759/codemirror-simple-mode-regex-not-highlighting-as-expected

Comment: @Gurman please make it an answer and I will mark it as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
\b(?:AND|OR|NOT)\b
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5MdEoY/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:AND|OR|NOT)` - matches either `AND` or `OR` or `NOT`
- `\b` - a word boundary

Answer (score 1):

This regex seems to meet your needs exactly as you described in your post,

```
\b(AND|NOT)\b(?:\s(OR)\s(NOT))?
```

**Regex explanation:**

- `\b(AND|NOT)\b` - This ensures the first group matches either `AND` or `NOT` as whole word, hence enclosed by word boundaries
- `(?:` - Start of a non-grouping optional group
- `\s(OR)\s(NOT)` - Matches a white space and a literal `OR` and places it in group 2 then again matches a white space and a literal `NOT` and places it in group 3
- `)?` - non-capturing group closed and `?` makes this group optional.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mR0B41/1)**

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.